# Should I use defer="defer" or defer?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the correct way of writing defer?
defer="defer" or defer

```
   <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

or

```
   <script type="text/javascript" defer src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: defer is a boolean attribute ( can have values true/false ) so only `defer`. But you should've been able to find info about this on the net. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) or on any other dozens of websites/forums. (Personal note : why upvote this question? :O )

Comment: I saw some articles using defer="defer", that's why I asked

Comment: a google would have given you ample results

Comment: Answer: Depends on DOCTYPE

Comment: Just search on MDN Docs. That's the best place to get info. `defer="defer"` is same as `defer=true`  or `defer=""` or `defer`. But the norm is clear that in case you have a true value you write just `defer`

Comment: @MihaiT The (html 5) norm is clear in that it has dropped any recommendation on which form to use. See Quentin's answer to the Q this one is marked as a duplicate of

Comment: @collapsar that answer is from 2013. in the docs linked now it says `Authors should be aware that many user agents only recognize the minimized form of boolean attributes and not the full form. For instance, authors may want to specify:

<OPTION selected>
instead of

<OPTION selected="selected">`

Comment: @MihaiT Sorry, but I think your statement is blatantly incorrect - see the specs from 12/2017 (W3C Html 5.2 recommendation): https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes. Btw, which user agents would not understand the verbose way to sepcify boolean attributes ?

Comment: @collapsar from the specs you linked `A boolean attribute without a value assigned to it (e.g. checked) is implicitly equivalent to one that has the empty string assigned to it (i.e. checked=""). As a consequence, it represents the true value.` So why am i not correct ?

Comment: @MihaiT Quote 'But the norm is clear that in case you have a true value you write just defer' - there is no mention of that in the current norm (though as I understand there has been in previous versions'. The recommendation for authors cannot be found in the standard; Your last quote just details semantics; it neither rules out nor recommends one form above the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176399/discussion-between-collapsar-and-mihai-t).